# WPF integrating with a web cam and rotating the video

Tags: wpf, video, webcam, rotation, flip

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have got the video displayed (see [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788075/wpf-integrating-with-web-cam)), set the display element's LayoutTransform or RenderTransform to a suitable RotateTransform.  If you wish to flip the video instead, use a ScaleTransform with a negative scale.  If you wish to do both, use a TransformGroup containing both a ScaleTransform and a RotateTransform.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the WPF [MediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/), which has code for webcams.  You can use standard WPF transforms to do your rotating.